# Camel Log Marker in Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

My logs format is JSON format and whenever I receive message immediately I set few parameters to header(additionalInfo), for all the logs default include the additionalInfo.

I tried the below in Java and success, but I need it in camel spring dsl

```
 logger.info(Markers.append("additionalInfo", Map), "Message Received");
```

Can someone please help me the possibility of the same in spring DSL. Mainly to set any Object in marker rather than just String.

Comment: Do you mean Spring XML? If so that is XML and NOT a programming language and therefore you cannot do above - you need to write a bit of Java code to do what you need.

Comment: Yes Spring XML. Thank you for the info.

Comment: What information from XML would you like to pass in as the Map, and what logger instance are you really using?

Comment: When I receive a msg I need to append sourceSytem,desinationSytem ,status fields and so on for all log's of type INFO/ERROR.  I am using logback which internally uses SLFJ